# If I have a JavaConstant.MethodHandle and I want to somehow pass it to MethodCall.invoke() is there a way to do it?

Tags: byte-buddy

Suppose I am generating a class using ByteBuddy.

Suppose further I have a `JavaConstant.MethodHandle` that I have somehow made.

Suppose now I want to use that `JavaConstant.MethodHandle` as a notional argument to `MethodCall.invoke()` as part of my class generation.  **Clearly at the moment I cannot do this**, since `MethodCall.invoke` takes, at best, a `MethodDescription`.  But the gist is: (a) I have found this `MethodHandle`, (b) `MethodHandle` instances can be stored in the constant pool, so {waves hands furiously} (c) ByteBuddy does magic and I can implement a generated method by saying `MethodCall.invoke(myMethodHandleConstantGoesHere)`.

So: **is it reasonable (or is it nonsensical) to talk about an enhancement to `MethodCall.invoke()` such that it could take a `JavaConstant.MethodHandle`** and do the magic to resolve it from the constant pool?

A couple of other interesting bits of background information:

- ByteBuddy says "[Note that constant MethodHandles cannot be represented within the constant pool of a Java class](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.MethodHandle.html)", which I [think is not true for modern JVMs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.8).  (I'm aware that ByteBuddy has to support JVMs going back to 1.5.)
- The [usage page for `JavaConstant.MethodHandle`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/utility/class-use/JavaConstant.MethodHandle.html) indicates that it is not really used outside of ByteBuddy's [`AgentBuilder.LambdaInstrumentationStrategy.LambdaInstanceFactory.LambdaMethodImplementation`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.17/net/bytebuddy/agent/builder/AgentBuilder.LambdaInstrumentationStrategy.LambdaInstanceFactory.LambdaMethodImplementation.html#LambdaMethodImplementation-net.bytebuddy.utility.JavaConstant.MethodHandle-net.bytebuddy.utility.JavaConstant.MethodType-) class.  Is it a viable structure for representing a `MethodHandle` in the constant pool for modern JVMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not possible but after your PR it will be in the next release. It will be possible from Byte Buddy 1.10.18.