# Why does JavaConstant.MethodHandle's documentation say that constant MethodHandles cannot be represented in a class' constant pool?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

The [javadoc for Byte Buddy's `JavaConstant.MethodHandle`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.11/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.MethodHandle.html) says:

> Note that constant `MethodHandle`s cannot be represented within the constant pool of a Java class

But [section 4.4.8 from the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.8), which is talking about a Java class' constant pool, says:

> The `CONSTANT_MethodHandle_info` structure is used to represent a method handle

What is Byte Buddy's documentation trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How embarrassing; it looks like the documentation is trying to tell me something about a state of affairs that I actually fixed. See: [If I have a JavaConstant.MethodHandle and I want to somehow pass it to MethodCall.invoke() is there a way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520610/if-i-have-a-javaconstant-methodhandle-and-i-want-to-somehow-pass-it-to-methodcal?rq=1)

I think this means this documentation is now simply incorrect, since in fact Byte Buddy representations of constant method handles *can* be stored in the constant pool.

Answer (score 0):

It might be referring to the fact that not *all* MethodHandles can be so represented.  From j.lang.invoke.MH's Javadoc:

> ...method handles that correspond to accessible fields, methods, and constructors can also be represented directly in a class file's constant pool as constants to be loaded by ldc bytecodes.

It might also be referring specifically to `JavaConstant.MethodHandle` instead of e.g. `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`.